# Third order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'''+6y''+10y'=0$

$r^3+6r^2+10r=0$

$r=-3+i,-3-i,0$

$y(x)=c_1e^{(3-i)x}+c_2e^{(-3+i)x}\sin x+c_3$

Now how do I get this in a different form? I'm sort of stuck. I'd appreciate a good explanation of how to use Euler's identity to do so.

Comment: Do you mean how $r$ emerges?

Comment: Somehow you can use euler's identity to get this in a form without complex numbers.

Comment: Why does one term have a $\sin x$ in it?

Comment: You also should have $e^{(-3-i)x}$, not $e^{(3-i)x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $\alpha \pm {\rm i}\beta$ as a root, you get a $Ae^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x)+Be^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)$ term in the solution. So: $$y = c_1 + c_2e^{-3x}\cos x + c_3 e^{-3x}\sin x.$$

You can justify that by looking at the ODE as $z'''+6z''+10z' = 0$, with $z$ a complex function. The result is that $z = {\rm Re}(z)+{\rm i}\,{\rm Im}(z)$ is a solution to $z'''+6z''+10z' = 0$ if and only if ${\rm Re}(z)$ and ${\rm Im}(z)$ are solutions of $y'''+6y''+10y'=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Imagine there are three function matching the differential equation:

$$y_1=e^{a x}$$

$$y_2=(\cos(b x)+c\times \sin(bx)) e^{dx}$$

$$y_3=(\cos(b x)-c\times \sin(bx)) e^{dx}$$

Put $y_1$, $y_2$ and $y_3$ into the equation and find $a,b,c,d$